# ¿Por qué ejecuta durante tanto tiempo para visualizar este array pequeño?

Tags: c++, string

tengo este código bastante sencillo pero no entiendo porque al ejecutarlo no para de trabajar hasta mostrarme esto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;


int main(){
string obra;
obra="C Cs D Ds E F Fs G Gs A As B";
for(int i=0;obra.size();i++){
    cout<<obra[i]<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Al cambiar `obra.size()`  por cualquier otra cosa, por ejemplo, `i<10`  no da problemas.

Comment: Y que valor devuelve obra.size? igual, ese for no esta bien... no estas comparando obra.size con nada...

Comment: `obra.size()` va a evauluar a un numero diferente de `0`. Por ende, la condicion de adentro del for siempre sera verdadera, haciendo que tu loop sea infinito. Coloca `i < obra.size()`.

Comment: El inconveniente es el siguiente. El formato de la sentencia for es: for(, , <avance/retroceso>). Entonces a vos en el for tenes mal escrita la condicion.

Comment: "Compilar" es el proceso de generar el binario. El problema no es que tarde en "compilar" si no en "ejecutar" (en tu caso, salir del bucle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El inconveniente es el siguiente. El formato de la sentencia for es:
for(, , <avance/retroceso>). Entonces a vos en el for tenes mal escrita la condicion. Al poner solamente obra.size() siempre dá TRUE como condicion porque cualquier valor distinto de 0 es true.
Para que funcione tendría que ser asi:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;


int main(){
string obra;
obra="C Cs D Ds E F Fs G Gs A As B";
for(int i=0;i < obra.size();i++){
    cout<<obra[i]<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración. Muchas horas programando hace que caigas en los errores más simplones. Un saludo.

Comment: @Luther me alegro que te haya servido la respuesta. Cuando tengas un minuto márcala como correcta por favor asi queda resuelto. Gracias